# How to make gap in the x axis using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I made a plot for presenting OR ratio. However, OR for log(PTH) has a large 95CI. Can I make a gap into x axis between 20 and 30, making other variables more visible? Some, examples suggest gap_plot(), but I do not know how to combine it with this type of graph.
I already transform PTH value, so it will be hard to change it regarding interpretation. If you have some other way to do it, feel free to suggest. I would like to make values of all variables visible.  However, this vales of lof(PTH) makes Pol hard to interpret from the plot, despite being significant.

Best,
A.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
Nezavisna<-c("Pol","Starost","Ca","P","log(PTH)","log(mg)","BrojZlezda","MIBI","Iskustvo","Pridruzena")
OR<-c(0.399,1.023,0.814,0.568,14.14,0.417,2.193,0.709,1.468,1.445)
LL<-c(0.174,0.996,0.277,0.122,4.969,0.197,1.019,0.339,0.754,0.702)
UL<-c(0.917,1.052,2.396,2.649,40.238,0.882,4.722,1.483,2.859,2.976)
istrazivanje<-data.frame(Nezavisna,OR,LL,UL)
istrazivanje
ggplot(istrazivanje, aes(y = Nezavisna, x = OR)) +geom_point(shape = 18, size = 5) +  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = LL, xmax = UL), height = 0.25) +  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, color = "red", linetype = "dashed", cex = 1, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Would switching to a log scale be an option? While there are options to add gaps or breaks it is in general not recommended. Therefore I would at least try `+ scale_x_log10()` or `scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2")`.

Comment: Stefan, thanks for you suggestion. I thought about that. However, It would be hard to interpret log of odds ratio.  OR around 1 is some common standard, especially among clinicians.  If I do now find any soultion, I would use log.

Comment: Stefan, I tried, and it looks great. Thanks a lot. But, how to interpret it.

Comment: The interpretation is still the same. We are still displaying the OR on the scale. But we are no longer displaying the values on a equidistant scale, i.e. in case of a log2 scale (which I or at least my brain prefers :D)  the distance between 2 and 4 is the same a between 4 and 8 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by stefan in the comments you can transform your data, but to make it readable set your labels and breaks to the normal values.

```
ggplot(istrazivanje, aes(y = Nezavisna, x = log2(OR))) +
  geom_point(shape = 18, size = 5) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = log2(LL), xmax = log2(UL)), height = 0.25) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log2(1), color = "red", linetype = "dashed", cex = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = log2(c(1, 10, 20, 30, 40)), labels =c(1, 10, 20, 30, 40))
```

[image]

Edit: or as you already take log(PTH) you could do log10(PTH) which roughly bring your OR value there from roughly 14 to 6 and perhaps then you do not even have to transform the scales of the graph.

Comment: Thanks Merijn. This is great. Stefan and you help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If, I understand correctly your question one solution could be `ggforce facet zoom function`

Sample code:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

ggplot(istrazivanje, aes(y = Nezavisna, x = OR)) +
  geom_point(shape = 18, size = 5) +  
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = LL, xmax = UL), height = 0.25) +  
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, 
             color = "red", 
             linetype = "dashed", 
             cex = 1, 
             alpha = 0.5)+
  facet_zoom(xlim = c(20, 30)) # use facet_zoom to zoom on x axis
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample data:

```
Nezavisna<-c("Pol","Starost","Ca","P","log(PTH)","log(mg)","BrojZlezda","MIBI","Iskustvo","Pridruzena")
    OR<-c(0.399,1.023,0.814,0.568,14.14,0.417,2.193,0.709,1.468,1.445)
    LL<-c(0.174,0.996,0.277,0.122,4.969,0.197,1.019,0.339,0.754,0.702)
    UL<-c(0.917,1.052,2.396,2.649,40.238,0.882,4.722,1.483,2.859,2.976)
    istrazivanje<-data.frame(Nezavisna,OR,LL,UL)
    istrazivanje
```

Comment: Thnaks for your assistance. Best, A.